# Error While POSTing to a third party PDF and additional parameters

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest, httppost

I am calling a rest api with multipart/form-data content type. I need to pass a pdf and additional parameters to generate a pdf. The appends the additional params data to the pdf and generate a new pdf. The additional param is an object like structure which I am able to generate using apex

```
QrInvoice= {  
"creditorInformation":  
    {  
    "iban": "CH3908704016075473007",  
    "creditor":  
        { 
            "addressType": "STRUCTURED",  
            "name": "Robert Schneider AG",  
            "streetName": "Rue du Lac",  
            "houseNumber": "1268/2/22", "postalCode": "2501",  
            "city": "Biel",  
            "addressLine1": "Rue du Lac 1268/2/22",  
            "addressLine2": "2501 Biel",  
            "country": "CH"  
        }  
    },  
"ultimateCreditor": {  
     "addressType": "STRUCTURED",  
     "name": "Robert Schneider Services Switzerland AG",  
     "streetName": "Rue du Lac",  
     "houseNumber": "1268/3/1",  
     "postalCode": "2501",  
     "city": "Biel",  
     "addressLine1": "Rue du Lac 1268/3/1",   
     "addressLine2": "2501 Biel",  
     "country": "CH"  
 },  
"paymentAmountInformation": {  
    "amount": 199.95,  
    "currency": "CHF"  
},  
"ultimateDebtor": {   
    "addressType": "STRUCTURED",   
    "name": "Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder",  
    "streetName": "Grosse Marktgasse",  
    "houseNumber": "28",  
    "postalCode": "9400",  
    "city": "Rorschach",  
    "addressLine1": "Rue du Lac 1268/3/1",   
    "addressLine2": "2501 Biel",  
    "country": "CH"  
},  
"paymentReference": {   
    "referenceType": "SCOR",   
    "reference": "RF18539007547034",  
    "additionalInformation": {  
    "unstructuredMessage": "Bill No. 3139 for garden work and disposal of cuttings",   
    "billInformation": "//S1/10/10201409/11/190512/20/1400.000-53/30/106017086/31/180508/32/7.7/40/2:10;0:30" }  
},  
"alternativeSchemes": {  
    "alternativeSchemeParameters": [  
    "Name AV1: UV;UltraPay005;12345"  
    ]  
}  
}
```

I am still getting bad request 400 error. I believe there is something wrong while passing params. Appreciate your help. Thanks
Here is my code

```
String file_name = 'testing.pdf';
       String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
        String header = '--'+boundary+'nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; QrInvoice='+addParam+';nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';

      String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';             
      String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'rnrn'));
        
        while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
        {
            header+=' ';
            headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'nn'));
        }
        //base64 encoded body
        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(retBlob);
        //base64 encoded footer
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        
        Blob bodyBlob = null;
        //last encoded body bytes
        String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
        if(last4Bytes.endsWith('='))
        {
            Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
            HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
            tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
            String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody()+footer;   
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
        }
        else
        {
            bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
        }
        
        if(bodyBlob.size()>3000000)
        {
            system.debug('--Excpetion--');
        }
  HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
  req1.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
  req1.setMethod('POST');
  req1.setEndpoint('https://rest.qr-invoice.cloud/v2/payment-part-receipt/append?fontFamily=LIBERATION_SANS&fontsEmbedded=true&boundaryLines=true&boundaryLineScissors=true&api_key=<API KEY>');  
  req1.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
  req1.setTimeout(60000);
  req1.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));
  Http http = new Http();
  HTTPResponse res1 = http.send(req1);
```

```
Demo Curl request boy which is working
```

-X POST "https://rest.qr-invoice.cloud/v2/payment-part-receipt/append?fontFamily=LIBERATION_SANS&fontsEmbedded=true&boundaryLines=true&boundaryLineScissors=true&api_key=" -H "accept: application/pdf" -H "Accept-Language: de" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "QrInvoice={ "creditorInformation": { "iban": "CH3908704016075473007", "creditor": { "addressType": "STRUCTURED", "name": "Robert Schneider AG", "streetName": "Rue du Lac", "houseNumber": "1268/2/22", "postalCode": "2501", "city": "Biel", "addressLine1": "Rue du Lac 1268/2/22", "addressLine2": "2501 Biel", "country": "CH" } }, "paymentAmountInformation": { "amount": 199.95, "currency": "CHF" }, "ultimateDebtor": { "addressType": "STRUCTURED", "name": "Pia-Maria Rutschmann-Schnyder", "streetName": "Grosse Marktgasse", "houseNumber": "28", "postalCode": "9400", "city": "Rorschach", "addressLine1": "Rue du Lac 1268/3/1", "addressLine2": "2501 Biel", "country": "CH" }, "paymentReference": { "referenceType": "SCOR", "reference": "RF18539007547034", "additionalInformation": { "unstructuredMessage": "Bill No. 3139 for garden work and disposal of cuttings", "billInformation": "//S1/10/10201409/11/190512/20/1400.000-53/30/106017086/31/180508/32/7.7/40/2:10;0:30" } }, "alternativeSchemes": { "alternativeSchemeParameters": [ "Name AV1: UV;UltraPay005;12345" ] } }" -F "pdf=@Rechnung - _Alpenstrasse 61 3052 Zollikofen_5.5 - ZWG - 1 OG.pdf;type=application/pdf"```

Comment: please reset your API key since it is public now.

Comment: this is demo key. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using the wrong characters in your line breaks. `rnrn` should be `\r\n\r\n` and `nn` should be `\n\n`.

Since you're not actually posting binary data, you could skip all the base64 encoding and write the string directly, but that's not causing the 400 error, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tried backslashed to r and n but no luck. The main question am I passing it correctly?